# Rails and the <span> tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html

I'm fairly new to Ruby on Rails, and I'm attempting to create some fancy CSS buttons using the "sliding doors" technique. I have it almost working, but I feel like there has to be a better way to handle the  tags for a link.

The way I'm currently doing it:

```
 <%= link_to '<span>New car</span>', {:action => "new"}, :class=>"button" %>
```

This isn't terrible, per se, but I would like to know if this is the best way to handle span tags in RoR.

Comment: There are *different* ways, but I think that you're using the best one.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Another option is this:

```
<%= link_to content_tag(:span, 'New car'), {:action => "new"}, :class=>"button" %>
```

[docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag)

Comment: Nice, this works really well. You can even add little icons to the button by doing:

<%= link_to content_tag(:span, 'New Car' + image_tag("car_add.png")), {:action => "new"}, :class=>"button" %>

Answer (score 7):

Or you could be pro and use named routes/resources + Haml. That would make it look like:

```
%a{ :href => new_car_path }
  %span New Car
```

What you have is fine though..

Answer (score 6):

If you're still curious, here are some ways to rewrite your code:

Use `content_tag`:

```
<%= link_to content_tag("span", "New car"), {:action => "new"}, :class=>"button" %>
```

Use `link_to` with a block:

```
<%= link_to {:action => "new"}, :class=>"button" do %>
  <span>New card</span>
<% end %>
```

And of course, you can combine the two by putting a `content_tag` inside the block, but I'll leave it to the reader as an exercise :)