# Embedded HTML in link_to body in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

What is the best way to go about getting embedded HTML in the body of a link generated with the link_to method?

I basically want the following:

```
<a href="##">This is a <strong>link</strong></a>
```

I have been trying to go about this as suggested in [Rails and the <span> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685436/rails-and-the-span-tag) but with no luck. My code looks like the following:

### item_helper.rb

```
def picture_filter
    #...Some other code up here
    text = "Show items with " + content_tag(:strong, 'pictures')
    link_to text, {:pics => true}, :class => 'highlight'
end
```

### item_view.html.erb

```
 #...
 <%=raw picture_filter %>
 #...
```

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Try it this way

```
<%= link_to(raw("a <strong>strong</strong> link"),{:pics => true},{ :class => 'highlight'})  %>
```

Comment: Applied to my example, the call became: link_to raw(text), {:pics => true}, :class => 'highlight'

Answer (score 62):

```
= link_to "http://www.example.com" do
   <strong>strong</strong>
```

Comment: ok I have just: `<%= link_to destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete do %>`

Answer (score 32):

As of 2016 I prefer this method.

```
<%= link_to my_path do %>
    This is a <strong>ape</strong>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I think it should  `<%= link_to my_path do %>
    This is a <strong>ape</strong>
<% end %>`

Answer (score 17):

you can use `html_safe`

```
<%= link_to ("<i class='someIcon'></i> Link").html_safe %>
```

Answer (score 4):

**Not sure if this is the best way.**

But I have been very successful in staking alot of the view helpers inside the content_tag call.

It also might not hurt to call a .html_safe

```
link_to(content_tag(:span, "Show yada " + content_tag(:strong, "Pictures")), {:pics => true})
```