# construct link_to in Rails 3.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Here my designer change the way to use anchor tag in html template, so I need to change in my rails template too,

if he placed below tag in approved html pages,

```
<a href="#">About Me</a>
```

I am converting it like this way

```
<%= link_to "About Me", '#' %>
```

Now if he placed `<a href="#">About <span> Me</a>` with span tag in title

```
 <ul>
       <li><a href="#">About <span>Me</span></a></li>
 </ul>
```

Here is the output, basically span tag break the line and display in second line

```
About
Me
```

Now I need help to convert this tag with rails 3.2.1 tag.

like `<%= link_to "About <span> Me</span>", '#' %>`

How can I do that? (I know that will generate error message)

Comment: Where does the span end? That doesn't look like valid HTML.

Comment: @JohnColvin - Just update the answer. Sorry I was missed the ending span

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embedded HTML in link_to body in Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317951/embedded-html-in-link-to-body-in-rails)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure rails doesn't escape the html tags.  You can do this either using html_safe or raw:

```
<%= link_to "About <span> Me</span>".html_safe, '#' %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to raw("About <span> Me</span>"), "#" %>
```

Comment: Note also that there is a comma between the display text and the hyperlink--the original question was missing the comma.

Comment: @EdJones - Good catch, I just change my question, Thanks

Comment: @EdJones - Thanks, that's works for me, I have one question Which one is best either html_safe or raw? if we consider best practices, performance, security point of view

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251284/raw-vs-html-safe-vs-h-to-unescape-html

Answer (score 1):

If wrapping the entire link in a span is alright, create a helper that does the following:

```
  def spanned_link_to(name,path=nil,options=nil)
    content_tag :span do
      link_to name, path, options
    end
  end
```

And use it as follows:

```
<%= spanned_link_to "About Me","#" %>
```

If not,

```
<%= link_to raw("About <span>Me</span>"),"#" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have link_to yield to a block. I'm not exactly sure what that looks like in ERB (I use HAML). You can write a link to like this, though:

```
link_to '#' do
  content_tag(:span, "About me")
end
```

or I think you can do a one liner like this:

```
link_to '#' { content_tag(:span, "About me") }
```

Comment: like mine, doesn't address just the 'Me'